# How to send an information from clickable table cells, using GET method?

Tags: html, forms, input, html-table, http-get

I have table with clickable td tags:

```
<table class="sala" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">A</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">7</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">13</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">14</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">15</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">16</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">17</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">B</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">7</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">13</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">14</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">15</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">16</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">17</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">C</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">7</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">13</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">14</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">15</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">16</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">17</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">D</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">7</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td colspan="5" rowspan="2" class="entry">WEJŚCIE</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">E</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">7</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">F</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="unactive">6</td>
    <td class="unactive">7</td>
    <td class="unactive">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td rowspan="5" class="entry"></td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">14</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">15</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">16</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">17</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">G</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">7</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">14</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">15</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">16</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">17</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">H</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="unactive">7</td>
    <td class="unactive">8</td>
    <td class="unactive">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">14</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">15</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">16</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">17</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">I</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">7</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">14</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">15</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">16</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">17</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th scope="row">J</th>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">1</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">2</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">3</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">4</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">5</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">6</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">7</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">8</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">9</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">10</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">11</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">12</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">14</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">15</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">16</td>
    <td class="noactive" onclick="javascript:$(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive');">17</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What looks like (yellow describe selected cells):

[image: Screen]

I want to send selected cells by GET method. I know that i need a form and input tags like radio buttons in my code but how to change it easily? Maybe there is something other solution to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it because I don't have all the code but I think I can help you. First, I think you should generate the table. It will help you if you want to edit it later. You can use a code like this to generate it:

```
<script>
    function createTable() {
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute("class", "sala");
        table.setAttribute("align", "center");
        var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
        var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tableBody.appendChild(createRow(letters[i]));
        }
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        return table;
    }

    function createRow(letter) {
        var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
        var tableHeader = document.createElement("th");
        tableHeader.innerHTML = letter;
        tableHeader.setAttribute("scope", "row");
        tableRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
            tableRow.appendChild(createDataCell(i));
        }
        return tableRow;
    }

    function createDataCell(value) {
        var tableDataCell = document.createElement("td");
        tableDataCell.innerHTML = value;
        tableDataCell.setAttribute("class", "noactive");;
        tableDataCell.onclick = function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive')
        };
        return tableDataCell;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(createTable()); // Edit this line to add it to what you want
 </script>
```

With that code you will have a table similar to your table. But you want to send these datas so I edited it to add hidden input. I think it will be better than radio buttons:

```
<script>
    function createTable() {
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute("class", "sala");
        table.setAttribute("align", "center");
        var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
        var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tableBody.appendChild(createRow(letters[i]));
        }
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        return table;
    }

    function createRow(letter) {
        var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
        var tableHeader = document.createElement("th");
        tableHeader.innerHTML = letter;
        tableHeader.setAttribute("scope", "row");
        tableRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
            tableRow.appendChild(createDataCell(letter, i));
        }
        return tableRow;
    }

    function createDataCell(letter, value) {
        var tableDataCell = document.createElement("td");
        tableDataCell.innerHTML = value;
        tableDataCell.setAttribute("class", "noactive");
        tableDataCell.onclick = function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('noactive')
            var currentValue = $(this).children().val();
            if(currentValue=="noactive"){
                $(this).children().val("active");
            }else{
                $(this).children().val("noactive");
            }
        };
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("value", "noactive");
        input.setAttribute("name", letter+value);
        tableDataCell.appendChild(input);
        return tableDataCell;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(createTable()); // Edit this line to add it to what you want
</script>
```

Now, you just need to put the table element in a form. Set the form method to get and add a submit button! :)

You had some active field in you exemple, I don't know what is the default value so in my exemple all is `noactive` . But if you want, add a function to edit the fields you want to change.

Also, hidden input name are letter+number. Ex: G12 or A1 or B17

Hope this can help, and if something is not working you can comment and I will see if I can to something more! :)

EDIT: I can't completly test it locally, so give me feedback! :) Also, depending of your need, it can be better to do it on the server side. Finally, the code need some improvements before production use!